# How to mark Spam message in MailCore2

Tags: email-spam, mailcore, mailcore2

In INBOX folder, I can Archive message by setting MCOMessageFlagDeleted.
But I want to mark message as Spam, I don't know which way to do that?

Comment: You can copy it to the spam folder (or add the spam label).

Comment: Have anyone got solutions?

Comment: You can do it with Dinh Viêt Hòa's recommendation